# How to click a Safari toolbar Extension button using AppleScript (when in full screen)

Tags: button, safari, applescript, toolbar, safari-extension

I'm trying to write a small AppleScript which will click the OneNote toolbar Extension, so I can bind it to a keyboard shortcut. The script below works perfectly as long as the instance of Safari is in windowed mode, but in full screen it fails and returns the error:

> error "System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of process \"Safari\". Invalid index." number -1719 from window 1 of process "Safari"

I have exported this script as an application and granted accessibility access to it. Effectively it seems as though a full screen Safari window is not given an index or is no longer a window and is now a different object.

```
tell application "System Events"
 tell process "Safari"
    click button whose description contains "OneNote" of toolbar 1 of window 1
 end tell 
end tell
```

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
OS X El Capitan, Version: 10.11.6 (15G1004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this script. It works whether Safari is in full screen mode or not:

```
set myButton to "OneNote"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set isfullscreen to value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1
        if isfullscreen is true then
            click ((buttons of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1) whose description contains myButton)
        else
            click ((buttons of toolbar 1 of window 1) whose description contains myButton)
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Replace "OneNote" with any button you'd like to click.

Comment: That script doesn't seem to work either, it returns the same error(error "System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of process \"Safari\". Invalid index." number -1719 from window 1 of process "Safari"). 
The line
    `set isfullscreen to value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1`
seems to be the problem, because when Safari is full screen, there doesn't seem to be any windows, "get every window" returns nothing?
Cheers for the reply!

Comment: To test the script I added "delay 3" in the first line. As soon as the script starts I switch over to the full screen Safari window. Can you please try it with the delay?

Comment: Also, have you allowed assistive access?
System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibility > Script Editor

Comment: Ok awesome its working! The script won't work if you've a single full screen safari window which isn't highlighted, but with the delay it worked perfectly!

When I went to create the Automator service(after taking out the delay) it stopped working again, and I had to give Safari Assistive Access as well(Automator already had it)

So its now working perfectly!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great, I'm glad that I could help! (Yes, the AppleScript will focus on any (non-full screen) application window first.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 2023 with Safari 16.2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised script based on [@oa-'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546103/12638282) which works with the latest version of macOS and Safari at the time of this writing (macOS Ventura 13.4 and Safari 16.5).

```
set target to "OneNote"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set isfullscreen to value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1
        if isfullscreen is true then
            click (first UI element of toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 whose description is target)
        else
            click (first UI element of toolbar 1 of window 1 whose description is target)
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```